# Get last modified file in a directory

Tags: php

Is there a way to select only the last file in a directory (with the extensions `jpg|png|gif`?)

Or do I have to parse the entire directory and check using `filemtime`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes you have to read through them all. But since directory accesses are cached, you shouldn't really worry about it.

```
$files = array_merge(glob("img/*.png"), glob("img/*.jpg"));
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filemtime", $files));
arsort($files);

$latest_file = key($files);
```

Comment: No. It's just a scandir() with a builtin filename filter. (I wrote a PHP4 reimplementation once). The real problem here is using two globs. It's quicker to use `glob("img/*.{png,jpg,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)` in your case.

Comment: True, scandir returns *all* entries. But glob filters it down already. The difference in the readdir approach is just that you do it in a stop-and-go fashion with more php/system calls.

Comment: glob does the looping in compiled C code, while readdir requires a slower PHP while loop.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to microoptimize this? Else I would suggest using an actual xdebug profiler run. (I'm betting 20¢ on glob.)

Comment: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler Optimizing PHP code on hearsay and assumptions won't get you any far.

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember having ever seen a function that would do what you ask.

So, I think you will have to go through all *(at least jpg/png/gif)* files, and search for the last modification date of each of them.

Here's a possible solution, based on the [**`DirectoryIterator`**][1] class of the SPL :

```
$path = null;
$timestamp = null;

$dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($dirname);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $timestamp) {
            // current file has been modified more recently
            // than any other file we've checked until now
            $path = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            $timestamp = $fileinfo->getMTime();
        }
    }
}

var_dump($path);
```

Of course, you could also do the same thing with [**`readdir()`**][2] and other corresponding functions.

Comment: php should have built-in such a function so we don't need to parse all dir .. imo

Comment: Writing this function is not that hard ;-) ;;; and you need seems a bit specific, so it might be understandable for core-developers to not want to implement such a function in PHP itself.

Comment: even tho you didn't checked for exstension lol i am going to accept this because i am sure readdir (or this equivalent) is faster than a glob + another parse

Comment: Oops, yep, I forgot the extension part ; sorry about that :-( too bad the `SplFileInfo::getExtension` method is only available with PHP >= 5.3.6 ( http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php )

Comment: i will just use to a simple readdir with a `preg_match(/\.(jpg|gif)$/i,$file)`

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN, yes that's a shame but at least it's in there now.  Also, an option would have been to wrap the `DirectoryIterator` (or, `FilesystemIterator`) in a `RegexIterator` to only iterate over the image files wanted. There's also a `GlobIterator`, which wouldn't have been much use here.

Answer (score 2):

```
function listdirfile_by_date($path)
{
    $dir = opendir($path);
    $list = array();
    while($file = readdir($dir))
    {
        if($file != '..' && $file != '.')
        {
            $mtime = filemtime($path . $file) . ',' . $file;
            $list[$mtime] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    krsort($list);

    foreach($list as $key => $value)
    {
        return $list[$key];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```