# php how to get last modified files in the dir

Tags: php, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get last modified file in a dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448374/get-last-modified-file-in-a-dir)

I have a folder which contents more than 30000 subfolders in it. How can I get a list of subfolders with last modification date >= one hour ago? Is it possible to do that without getting a list of all files in an array and sorting it? I cannot use a `readdir` function because it returns files in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem and exhaustive search of the list of files will take a very long time.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: @SherinJose I know how to get a time of last modification of the file. But how can it help in my task?

Comment: @NullPointer No, it isn't. I need to get last modified files without getting all contents of the dir in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GNU Find - it is simpler and faster!

```
find [path] -type d -mmin +60
```

Comment: Thank you. I will think about it, but what about Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The linux "find" command is pretty powerful.

```
$cmd = "find ".$path." type -d -mmin +60";
$out=`$cmd`;
$files=explode("\n",$out);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Give this a try:

<?php
$path = 'path/to/dir';

if (is_dir($path)) {
  $contents = scandir($path);

  foreach ($contents as $file) {
    $full_path = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      if (is_dir($full_path)) {
        $dirs[filemtime($full_path)] = $file;
      }
    }
  }

  // Sort in reverse order to put newest modification at the top
  krsort($dirs);

  $iteration = 0;

  foreach ($dirs as $mtime => $name) {
    if ($iteration != 5) {
      echo $name . '<br />';
    }

    $iteration++;
  }
}
?>
```