# Finding latest file's name and modification time in PHP

Tags: php, glob, filemtime

I search a director with `glob` function and get the matched files' list. Then by checking `filemtime` of the files I create a map. Then sort the map with respect to file dates. At last I get latest file's name and modification time. My code is like this. It works well for small directories, but it's slow for big directories. I wonder whether is there a faster/clever way?

```
$fileList = array();
// $id = is the argument of this function
$files = glob('myfolder'.DS.'someone'.$id.'*.txt');
if (empty($files)) {
    return 0;
}
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileList[filemtime($file)] = $file;
}

if (sizeof($files) > 1) {
    ksort($fileList);
}

$latestFilename = end($fileList);
$fileLastModifDate = filemtime( $latestFilename );
```

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124958/glob-sort-by-date) gives various possiblities (esp the link in the first comment which has some very clever ideas). You would probably have to benchmark each yourself to determine which was the fastest.

Comment: Do you only need to know which file is the last modified? If so, building a list and sorting it is not required.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448374/get-last-modified-file-in-a-dir

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that your "mapping" is actually creating a hash table, and then the sort is not efficiant as one might expect, i would try this: (this is the basic, u can fancy it up)

```
class file_data
{
   public  $time; // or whatever u use
   public $file;
}

$arr =new array ();
foreach ($files as $file) {
     $new_file = new file_data ();
     $file_data->time = filetime($file);
     $file_data->file = $file;   
     array_push ($arr,$file_data);
}

function file_object_compare ($a,$b)
{
    if ($a->time > $b->time) return -1;
//    etc... i.e 0 eual 1 otherwise

}

//and then u sort
usort ($arr,"file_object_compare");
```

// or 
//  and this is probably better, if u only need this paricular sorting

```
function file_object_compare ($a,$b)
{
    if (filetime($a)> filetime($b)) return -1;
//    etc... i.e 0 eual 1 otherwise    
}

usort ($files,"file_object_compare");
```