# Using JQuery or PHP to pull latest image?

Tags: php, jquery, image

I was trying to figure out a way to have JQuery (if possible) to display the latest image from a directory, regardless of its file name.  Basically, I just want a simple  tag to be updated to show the image.  I realize this might not be possible with Jquery, so my fallback would be PHP.

I've been trying to research how to do this, but honestly do not know where to start.  Any tips to get going would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with JQuery, you can! You only need to add a few lines of logic to your app.

For example, when you add images to that folder, also write a text file with the name of the image just added. Then this text file is going to always have the filename of the last image uploaded. Finally, using JavaScript(with JQuery or anything else) you do one request to the text file and then you do the second request to obtain the image with that filename.

That is just a very basic example to try to share the idea of how to do it, then depending your particular case, you can add or change a lot of details to make this works for your case.

BTW, to do it with PHP, you are going to need to execute a system command, for example 'ls -ltrh' and parse the output to obtain the last filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP script to get latest modified file in a specific directory.

Code can be found here: [Get last modified file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448374/get-last-modified-file-in-a-dir)

You then can format that into JSON which can be passed through a jQuery AJAX call http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

With those 2 techniques, you can manipulate the data to display the image.