# Check last js/css file in folder

Tags: php

I am building up a simple PHP script to get all my site css/js files combined.

What I would like to do now is checking for the most recent built css or js file in the "cache" folder.

So... some function like:

```
function getLastFile('js'){
   return the js file name
}

function getLastFile('css'){
   return the css file name
}
```

I've found out solutions on the net on how to check for the last file in some folder... but how can I exactly check the last by a specific extension?

Comment: You can use `glob('cache/*.js')`.

Comment: may be easier to use the os native functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

For getting the js files, use `glob('cache/*.js');` and for css `glob(cache/*.css);`
And you can use [filetime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the latest modified file.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448374/get-last-modified-file-in-a-dir) question.

Comment: +1, this method is awesome. Note that you can run foreach on it.

Answer (score 0):

if u mean last as  `most recent built`

```
//get the last-modified-date of this very file
$lastModifiedTime=filemtime($Cachedfile);
```

or better have a look over the [smartoptimizer](http://farhadi.ir/projects/smartoptimizer/) Code , have a tiny look through its source u will surely get an idea